# What does the target ".cpp.o:" mean in a Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I'm learning the GNU makefile. I came across this page: http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/

At the end of this article, I found this:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=hello

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Could anyone explain what's in OBJECT variable and what target `.cpp.o:` means (also the `$<` in it)?

I also found when I use something like:

```
SRC = $(wildcard $(SRC_DIR)*.c)
SRC_OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRC))
```

and use "$(SRC_OBJS)" as a target, it will compile all objects for each required object. This doesn't happen for the first one. What's the difference?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a **suffix rule** telling make how to turn `file.cpp` into `file.o` for an arbitrary `file`.

`$<` is an automatic variable referencing the source file, `file.cpp` in the case of the suffix rule.

`$@` is an automatic variable referencing the target file, `file.o`.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the name, I searched the "suffix rule" and saw it is well explained in GNU document. That solved my problem.

Comment: @MingchenZhang Great! The next step on Stackoverflow is to upvote/accept the answer you found most useful (sometimes there is a minimum time before you can do so, or a minimum reputation needed).

Comment: But where it says that the extension ".cpp" is to be used? Is it in the target ".cpp.o"? If I want to create a rule that converts .ext1 into .ext2 then I need to start a rule with "ext1.ext2"? What does the "OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)" do indeed?

Comment: @AntonAndreev It's in the *suffix rule* (not target) `.cpp.o`. Yes it would be `.ext1.ext2`. The assignment to OBJECTS takes all words in SOURCES and replaces `.cpp` with `.o`. See your make manual for details.